# Wordpress get_pages meta_key don't show page

Tags: navigation

I'm using get_pages in a Wordpress theme to create the nav.

I have some pages I don't want to show in the nav.

On all pages I have a 'dont_show_in_nav' true/false custom field.

I can use meta_key to add pages that have 'dont_show_in_nav' selected
but I'd like to not show the pages that have 'dont_show_in_nav' selected.

I could create a 'show_in_nav' custom field and select all the pages to show but I have to many pages to do that.

I've tried `'meta_value' => false`

```
    $pages_args = array(
      'sort_column' => 'menu_order',
      'parent' => 0,
      'post_type' => 'page',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'meta_key'  => 'dont_show_in_nav',
      'meta_value' => true
    );
```

Comment: Are you certain your custom field contains true/false booleans and not just the text true/false ?
If not, try setting your meta_value to: 'true' - With the '' symbols (ticks).

Answer (score 0):

For the reasons I probably don't want to hear about, curiously `get_pages()` does not actually uses `WP_Query` internally. Like every other way to retrieve posts does.

From a quick look a source it always treats `meta_value` as string, which I would guess is the reason for you not getting expected behavior.

I would suggest to try use `get_posts()` instead for more consistency with *usual* mechanics.